# Regex to find continuous characters in the word and remove the word

Tags: python, regex, r, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to find whether a particular character is occurring continuously in the a word of the string or find if the word contains only numbers and remove those as well. For example,

```
df
All aaaaaab the best 8965
US issssss is 123 good 
qqqq qwerty 1 poiks
lkjh ggggqwe 1234 aqwe iphone5224s
```

I want to check for two conditions, where in the first condition check for repeating characters more than 3 times and also check if a word  contains only numbers. I want to remove only when the word contains only numbers and when a character occurs more than 3 times continuously in the word.

the following should be the output,

```
df
All the best 
US is good 
qwerty poiks
lkjh aqwe iphone5224s
```

The following are my trying,

`re.sub('r'\w[0-9]\w*', df[i])` for number. but this is not removing single character numbers. Also for the repeated characters, I tried, `re.sub('r'\w[a-z A-Z]+[a-z A-Z]+[a-z A-Z]+[a-z A-Z]\w*', df[i])` but this is removing every word here. instead of repeated letter.

Can anybody help me in solving these problems?

Comment: So, you also need to handle the whitespace, too? Remove before the word or after, depending on the word position? And is the `R` or `Python` tag relevant?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can handle the spaces by using re.sub(' +',' ',x) along with lstrip, rstrip on top of  it. The reason for taggin R and python is, I am open to do this in both the coding languages. So either of the language is fine.

Comment: `\w` matches a word, I think you want to be using `\b` to match a word boundary. With that fix, I believe the pattern you want for digits is `\b[0-9]+\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest

```
\s*\b(?=[a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])\1{3}|\d+\b)[a-zA-Z\d]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA0aS0/1)

Only alphanumeric words are matched with this pattern:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])\1{3}|\d+\b)` - there must be at least 4 repeated consecutive letters or digits in the word OR the whole word must consist of only digits
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - a word with 1+ letters or digits.

[Python demo:](http://ideone.com/5OiEtS)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\s*\b(?=[a-z\d]*([a-z\d])\1{3}|\d+\b)[a-z\d]+', re.IGNORECASE)
s = "df\nAll aaaaaab the best 8965\nUS issssss is 123 good \nqqqq qwerty 1 poiks\nlkjh ggggqwe 1234 aqwe iphone5224s"
strs = s.split("\n")                   # Split to test lines individually
print([p.sub("", x).strip() for x in strs])
# => ['df', 'All the best', 'US is good', 'qwerty poiks', 'lkjh aqwe iphone5224s']
```

Note that `strip()` will remove remaining whitespaces at the start of the string.

A similar solution in R with a TRE regex:

```
x <- c("df", "All aaaaaab the best 8965", "US issssss is 123 good ", "qqqq qwerty 1 poiks", "lkjh ggggqwe 1234 aqwe iphone5224s")
p <- " *\\b(?:[[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]])\\1{3}[[:alnum:]]*|[0-9]+)\\b"
gsub(p, "", x)
```

See a [demo](http://ideone.com/k51nyu)

*Pattern details* and [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL0wE8/1):

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:[[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]])\1{3}[[:alnum:]]*|[0-9]+)` - either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `[[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]])\1{3}[[:alnum:]]*` - 0+ alphanumerics followed with the same 4 alphanumeric chars, followed with 0+ alphanumerics
  - `|`  - or
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

UPDATE:

To also add an option to remove 1-letter words you may use

1. **R** (add `[[:alpha:]]|` to the alternation group): `\s*\b(?:[[:alpha:]]|[[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]])\1{3}[[:alnum:]]*|[0-9]+)\b` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL0wE8/3))
2. **Python** lookaround based regex ([add](https://regex101.com/r/qA0aS0/2) `[a-zA-Z]\b|` to the lookahead group): `*\b(?=[a-zA-Z]\b|\d+\b|[a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])\1{3})[a-zA-Z\d]+`

Comment: Thanks.. it worked. Can you also help me in identifying single letter words? for ex, a , s .. for identifying these?

Comment: Single letter words - add `|[a-zA-Z]\b` to the alternatives in the Python solution. See [`\s*\b(?=[a-zA-Z]\b|\d+\b|[a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])\1{3})[a-zA-Z\d]+`](https://regex101.com/r/qA0aS0/2).

Comment: But doesn't that remove every word which contains a-z or A-Z ?

Comment: for ex, re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]', ' ', 'qqqq qwerty 1 poiks s') gives output of only 1

Comment: You must have used the regex incorrectly. See [`re.sub(r'\s*\b(?=[a-zA-Z]\b|\d+\b|[a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])\1{3})[a-zA-Z\d]+', '', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/qA0aS0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are easy:

```
re.sub(r'\d+', '', s)
```

If you want to remove words where the same letter appears twice, you can use capturing groups (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
re.sub(r'\w*(\w)\1\w*', '', s)
```

Putting those together:

```
re.sub(r'\d+|\w*(\w)\1\w*', '', s)
```

For example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\d+|\w*(\w)\1\w*', '', 'abc abbc 123 a1')
'abc   a'
```

You may need to clean up spaces afterwards with something like this:

```
>>> re.sub(r' +', ' ', 'abc   a')
'abc a'
```